# Error with ContentValues in Android (Eclipse IDE)

Tags: android, eclipse, syntax-error

I'm trying to make a ContentValues in Android with the Eclipse IDE.

This is my code:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("name", "Cs Tech");
```

Eclipse returns this error in the second line:

> Multiple markers at this line
>       - Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens 
>       - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct
>        (s)

When I click the error picture (the cross on a red circle), It selects the dot (.)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you missing a curly brace anywhere else above that code? Eclipse cannot parse properly past some syntax errors, so it gets confused on where the actual error is. You might want to post more of your code to help us answer your question.

Comment: put more code so one can find an error.